# Does __reduce__ accept arguments?

Tags: python, pickle

When I read code from others, I found someone defines `__reduce__` for the class accepting arguments. For instance, [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/base.py#L547). If you are not aware, `__reduce__` magic method is for pickling a Python object.

```
    def __reduce__(self, args=(), kwargs=None):
        kwargs = {} if not kwargs else kwargs
        return (unpickle_backend, (self.__class__, args, kwargs))
```

So I quote the [document](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__):

> The interface is currently defined as follows. The `__reduce__()` method takes **no argument** and shall return either a string or preferably a tuple (the returned object is often referred to as the “reduce value”).

Anyone help me understand?

Comment: The method definition as shown is perfectly compatible with not accepting any arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pickle machinery will only ever call `__reduce__` without arguments. Celery has chosen to overload their `__reduce__` implementations to support arguments; these arguments are used by Celery internally, and are not provided by the pickle machinery. Since the extra arguments are optional, these `__reduce__` methods can still handle no-argument calls, and they are still compatible with the `__reduce__` protocol.

For example, [`celery.backends.rpc.RPCBackend.__reduce__`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.3.0/celery/backends/rpc.py#L321) looks like this:

```
def __reduce__(self, args=(), kwargs={}):
    return super(RPCBackend, self).__reduce__(args, dict(
        kwargs,
        connection=self._connection,
        exchange=self.exchange.name,
        exchange_type=self.exchange.type,
        persistent=self.persistent,
        serializer=self.serializer,
        auto_delete=self.auto_delete,
        expires=self.expires,
    ))
```

It passes a non-empty `kwargs` argument to `super().__reduce__`. The delegated-to `__reduce__` implementation can handle that, but it's not a call the pickle machinery would ever make directly.